# Java Spring Hibernate Dependency issues when modifying a project to use Maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've been working on a small finance app to improve my knowledge of Spring and Hibernate.  I initially started creating it by adding the decencies directly to the class-path.  I have tried to update my project to use Maven and updated from Spring (4.3.9) to (5.0.1) and I am currently getting the below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController' defined in file [C:\Users\Lex-Man\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\LexBudget\WEB-INF\classes\org\lexusmanson\lexbudget\controller\TestController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

My POM file is listed below:

```
      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My Spring configuration file is listed below:

```
    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.lexusmanson.lexbudget" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Define Tiles Resolver -->
    <!-- <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" /> 
    </bean> -->

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="lexDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/lex_budget?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="lexbudget" />
        <property name="password" value="" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="lexDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.lexusmanson.lexbudget.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!--  Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ...  -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>

</beans>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you mixing Spring 1 and Spring 5!... Remove `spring-hibernate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

integration of Spring 5 and Hibernate 5 with below versions works for me.

Spring - 5.0.0.RELEASE

Hibernate - 5.2.11.Final

May be you can try this combination.

For more you can refer this link :

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring5-mvc-hibernate5-example/

Comment: Changed all my dependencies to yours and it worked.  Thanks for your help would give you a point but don't have the rep.